# Software to track the CPU usage of individual processese and generate alert

Tags: windows, monitoring, system-monitor

I'm looking for a software tool, preferably free , that can **monitor CPU and memory usage for individual processes**, specifically for SQL, **for 10-second intervals**. The tool should *generate an alert, such as an email or popup notification, if the CPU usage for the entire 10 seconds exceeds say 75%*.

I've researched some tools such as ***Process Explorer and Process Monitor*** from Sysinternals, but they don't have an alerting feature. **Process Lasso** (whose features matches my requirement) and ***SysGauge*** have alerting options, but they are only *available in the paid versio*n. I also tested ***ManageEngine OpManager***, but it didn't work properly and was *difficult to configure*. Additionally, I tried using the ***Performance Monitor (perfmon.exe)*** and added the counter, but it didn't generate an alert.

I have also tried using Event Sentry free edition, it meets the same requirement but works using Event-logs. When I set the threshold for the process counter to generate an alert , it did not work. Not easy to configure and use as well.

Can you recommend any free or paid tools that meet these requirements? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is possibly an XY issue. Why would you like to monitor the processes? If you want to e.g. analyze what those processes are doing during that time, you could use [procdump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump). It does not have an alert feature, but it will collect the necessary data for the analysis.

Comment: I could use procdump , but I am in need of a tool that can generate an Alert if any exe or process exceeds the set threshold

Answer (score 1):

After going through webpages from google search , I have found few tools that can be used. EventSentry free edition or Process Lasso from bitsum can be used for the same purpose.

If third party tools are not proffered then PerfMon (or Windows Performance Monitor) can be used to collect Process Counters dataset values and an Alert can be triggered.
Better option is to automate the above using PowerShell script.